# SuiteScript: How does the dynamic mode of nlobjColumn.setURL work?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

In NetSuite, I have a scripted search of transactions that is expected to return results of several different transaction types. The results are then rendered in an `nlobjList`. I would like one of the columns of said list to be a link to the transaction that the list row represents.

In all NetSuite examples, this is accomplished something like:

```
var column = list.addColumn('number', 'text', 'Number', 'left');
column.setURL(nlapiResolveURL('RECORD','salesorder'));
column.addParamToURL('id','id', true);
```

Unfortunately, `transaction` is not an acceptable record type to pass to `nlapiResolveURL`, so I would need to dynamically detect the record type for each row. The `setURL` function does accept a second Boolean parameter that makes it dynamic per row, but I am not sure how this actually works. There are no examples, and the JSDocs do not explain its usage.

Does anyone have any guidance on generating a list with dynamic URLs in NetSuite?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to maybe the dynamic flag work either, so I just hardcoded the generic transaction path… column.setURL('/app/accounting/transactions/transaction.nl');

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `dynamic` argument to true, then the first argument should be a column listed in the data source that will contain the base URL.

```
column.setURL('base_url', true);
column.addParamToURL('id','id', true);
```

Then, on each record of your results, make sure you have a `base_url` that is set to the url you are looking for.

Note, the following example assumes a regular javascript object instead of the search result object.

```
rec.base_url = nlapiResolveURL('RECORD', rec.type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Transaction field is just an abstraction for all transaction types. You can search them but can't load them.

The field you need to retrieve is **recordtype**. Sample code is below.

```
var recs = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction',null,null,new nlobjSearchColumn('recordtype'));
for(var i in recs) 
   url = nlapiResolveURL('RECORD',recs[i].getValue('recordtype'));
```

Comment: I do not have search results at the time I am constructing the `nlobjList`, so I cannot inspect them for record types. I also cannot redefine the base URL for the `nlobjColumn` as I am processing results. The base URL for the list column is set at the time of list construction using the `nlobjColumn.setURL` function. This function has a "dynamic" mode that apparently calculates the base URL for each row, which is what I need, but I cannot determine how it works. That is the question - how does the `nlobjColumn.setURL` function dynamically?